# Pass state through Navigator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm using the React Native core Navigator component but having trouble figuring out how to pass data between components when pressing buttons in the Navigation Bar. Here is some example code of the setup that I have.

```
const NavigationBarRouteMapper = {
  Title: (route, navigator) => {
    let title;
    switch (route.component.displayName) {
      case 'FirstScreen':
        title = 'First Screen';
        break;
    }

    return (
      <Text>
        {title}
      </Text>
    )
  },
  LeftButton: (route, navigator) => {
    let onButtonPress, buttonTitle;
    switch (route.component.displayName) {
      case 'SecondScreen':
        buttonTitle = 'Close';
        onButtonPress = () => navigator.pop();
        break;
    }

    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={onButtonPress}>
        <Text>
          {buttonTitle}
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    )
  },
  RightButton: (route, navigator) => {
    let onButtonPress, buttonTitle;
    switch (route.component.displayName) {
      case 'SecondScreen':
        buttonTitle = 'Save';
        onButtonPress = () => {}; // @TODO Call onButtonPress in SecondScreen component
        break;
    }

    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={onButtonPress}>
        <Text>
          {buttonTitle}
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
};

const App = React.createClass({
  renderScene(route, navigator) {
    return <route.component navigator={navigator} {...route.props} />;
  },
  render() {
    return (
      <Navigator
        style={styles.appContainer}
        initialRoute={{component: SplashScreen}}
        renderScene={this.renderScene}
        navigationBar={
          <Navigator.NavigationBar
            routeMapper={NavigationBarRouteMapper}
          />
        }
      />
    );
  }
});

const FirstScreen = React.createClass({
  onButtonPress() {
    this.props.navigator.push({component: SecondScreen});
  },
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.onButtonPress}>
          <Text>
            Click Me
          </Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    );
  }
});

const SecondScreen = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      input: ''
    }
  },
  onButtonPress() {
    if (this.state.input.length) {
      // Do something with this.state.input such as POST to remote API
      this.props.navigator.pop();
    }
  },
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput
          onChangeText={(input) => this.setState({input})}
          value={this.state.input}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
});
```

You can see from the comments that I have a value stored in the state of SecondScreen that I want to do something with when someone hits the Save button. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In your renderScene function, while returning 'route.component' you can pass props and read them in the component.